# Finding probability given mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, standard-deviation

I don't know how to approach this problem:

X is normally distributed with a mean of 200 and a standard deviation of 10.

Find `P(X ≥ 203)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standardize so that you can use the standard normal distribution to find the numerical value for the answer.  So, we have
$$\begin{align} \mathbb{P}(X \geq 203) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X - 200}{10} \geq \frac{203 -200}{10}\right) \\ &= \mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq \frac{3}{10}\right) \\ &= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(Z < \frac{3}{10}\right) \\ &= 1-\Phi\left(\frac{3}{10}\right) \,\,, \end{align}$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function.